# Nginx Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 443

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

This store using WooCommerce has been set up for years. Today I got the complain from customers about this error. I checked it and found out that the css/js/images couldn't be loaded. Does anyone know the solution?

I disabled most of the plugin, used the simple configuration but nothing helped.

Comment: There is no 443 error code

Comment: All images/js/css GET with 443 error. That's really weird.

Comment: I get net::ERROR_ABORTED 443

Answer (score 0):

Try browsing your website with ssl on port 80 by using "http://" in place of "https://" if it works then, It could be a issue related to https setup or the ssl certificate.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating my server, kill all nginx process and start it again. All errors seemed to be gone.